# apachebench symfony2 logged in pages benchmark

Tags: symfony, curl, apachebench

I'm trying to benchmark a symfony application and therefore I also need to benchmark the pages that are restricted to users that are logged in.

I want to benchmark the application using the apachebench tool and therefore wrote a small shell script that tries to login with curl, fetch the phpsessid returned from the request and set it as a cookie in the apachebench command.

Here is what the shellscript looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

COOKIE_JAR="/var/www/apachebench/test.jar"

curl -c $COOKIE_JAR --data "_email=admin%40dummy.at&_password=test&_target_path=%2Fbackend" http://symfony.local/login

PHPSESSID=$(cat $COOKIE_JAR | grep PHPSESSID | cut -f 7)

ab -n 10 -p /var/www/apachebench/albumpostfile.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -C PHPSESSID=$PHPSESSID -k  http://symfony.local/album/add
```

The apachebench command should post a form and store the data in a database. However it looks like I'm not getting logged in because the data aren't stored and I tried the command before using a PHPSESSID that I copied from my browser and it worked perfectly fine. I also already disabled the csrf protection globally.

I also already checked if the PHPSESSID returned from the curl is correctly inputted into the ab command and it is.

I totally have no clue what I'm doing wrong as I tried to post the exact same data to the login page through the chrome extension "POSTMAN" and it works there.

The cookie-jar file from the curl request looks as followed:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

symfony.local   FALSE   /       FALSE   0       PHPSESSID       t2glc67hlf6lrlik2ieg9r7rv7
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
That is the output of apachebench when I add -v 3 to the command

```
WARNING: Response code not 2xx (302)
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 12:03:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Location: http://symfony.local/login
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://symfony.local/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://symfony.local/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://symfony.local/login">http://symfony.local/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
WARNING: Response code not 2xx (302)
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 12:03:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Location: http://symfony.local/login
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

EDIT2:
So this is my new shell script, I altered it, so that the curl command sends a PHPSESSID cookie with its request. Below you can see the different outputs from both scripts. It looks like the second one is working as it states the correct url in the **Redirecting to Url** part. But this time the apachebench command isn't doing anything at all, it just gets stuck.

```
#!/bin/bash

COOKIE_JAR="/var/www/apachebench/test.jar"

#curl -c $COOKIE_JAR -v -d "_email=admin%40dummy.at&_password=test&_target_path=%2Fbackend" -b "PHPSESSID=1hrfrnud407n5j42oki13655g7" http://symfony.local/login
curl -c $COOKIE_JAR -v -d "_email=admin%40dummy.at&_password=test&_target_path=%2Fbackend" http://symfony.local/login

PHPSESSID=$(cat $COOKIE_JAR | grep PHPSESSID | cut -f 7)

ab -n 10 -p /var/www/apachebench/albumpostfile.txt -T application/x-www-form-urlencoded -C PHPSESSID=$PHPSESSID http://symfony.local/album/add
```

**OLD-CURL-OUTPUT:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* Connected to symfony.local (127.0.1.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: symfony.local
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 62
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 62 out of 62 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 12:39:05 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
* Added cookie PHPSESSID="l2pfvtum211bd8tnpp1i0vpcj1" for domain symfony.local, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=l2pfvtum211bd8tnpp1i0vpcj1; path=/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Location: http://symfony.local/login
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://symfony.local/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://symfony.local/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://symfony.local/login">http://symfony.local/login</a>.
    </body>
* Connection #0 to host symfony.local left intact
</html>
```

**NEW-CURL-OUTPUT:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.1.1...
* Connected to symfony.local (127.0.1.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /login HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: symfony.local
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: PHPSESSID=1hrfrnud407n5j42oki13655g7
> Content-Length: 62
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 62 out of 62 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 12:40:07 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
* Added cookie PHPSESSID="3ehl5ldkbd4ngl2er663899km1" for domain symfony.local, path /, expire 0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3ehl5ldkbd4ngl2er663899km1; path=/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Location: http://symfony.local/backend
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://symfony.local/backend" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://symfony.local/backend</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://symfony.local/backend">http://symfony.local/backend</a>.
    </body>
* Connection #0 to host symfony.local left intact
</html>This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking symfony.local (be patient)...
```

The Last line of the output is where the ab command gets stuck.

Comment: Maybe you get some errors. Try adding `-v 3` to `ab` command and see what `html` is rterurned. Maybe it will helps you.

Comment: I'll post the response in an answer because it is to long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it is working now.

The second command was perfectly fine so I you really need to pass a PHPSESSID cookie to the call of the login if you benchmark symfony.

The reason why it hung up on the apachebench command wasn't related to the shell script but due to a missing { in the code that I accidently deleted when trying to debug it. By looking into the apache2 error.log file I was able to figure it out.

So if anyone else will have the same problem keep in mind to add a PHPSESSID cookie to your curl command and the login will work and you can benchmark pages that need a login.